# Child Fragment under Tabbed Activity is not working

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I am working on Tabbed Activity.
On Daily Reminder/Special Reminder, the save button is just not working.
I have given the proper id, linking and OnClickListener. But it just doesn't work.

[Reminders Activity is a simple activity with List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/du9bc.png)
[ReminderTabActivity s Tabbed Activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hcCWM.png)
Over here is onCreateView of ReminderTabActivity where the fragment is being called.

```
public class ReminderTabActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements DailyReminderFragment.OnMessageSetListener {

    /**
     * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
     * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
     * {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which will keep every
     * loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory intensive, it
     * may be best to switch to a
     * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
     */
    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    /**
     * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
     */
    private ViewPager mViewPager;

    String type = "";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_reminder_tab);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
        // primary sections of the activity.
        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra("key")) {
            String key = intent.getStringExtra("key");
            type = intent.getStringExtra("etype");
            Log.d("mKey", key);
            if(type.equals("special")) {
                mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                SpecialReminderFragment srf = new SpecialReminderFragment();
                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString("key", key);
                srf.setArguments(bundle);
                //srf.updateSpecial(key);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_reminder_tab, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    @Override
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        Log.d("messageSet", message);
    }

    /**
     * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
     */
    public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
        /**
         * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
         * fragment.
         */
        private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

        public PlaceholderFragment() {
        }

        /**
         * Returns a new instance of this fragment for the given section
         * number.
         */
        public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
            PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
            fragment.setArguments(args);
            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==1) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily_reminder, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else if(getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)==2) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_special_reminder, container, false);
                return rootView;
            }
            else {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_reminder_tab, container, false);
                TextView textView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.section_label);
                textView.setText(getString(R.string.section_format, getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
                return rootView;
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
     * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
     */
    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
            // Return a PlaceholderFragment (defined as a static inner class below).
            return PlaceholderFragment.newInstance(position + 1);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 2 total pages.
            return 2;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "DAILY REMINDER";
                case 1:
                    return "SPECIAL REMINDER";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}





@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d("kedar", "ONLOAD");
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_daily_reminder, container, false);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    btn_save = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btn_save);
    etTitle = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.etTitle);
    picker = (TimePicker) rootView.findViewById(R.id.timePicker);
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    btn_save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            saveReminder();
            OnMessageSetListener.setMessage("test");
        }
    });

    return rootView;
}
```

Here is the layout-
`

```
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/etTitle"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView5"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:hint="Title"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <TimePicker
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/etTitle"
        android:id="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" />

    <Button
        android:text="SAVE"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/btn_save"
        android:layout_below="@+id/timePicker"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

`

I can see the layout, but it is not displaying the Log.d message in the console nor is the button onClickListener functioning.
What do you folks think I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Please, post also your layout

Comment: @FlyingPumba Check now. What do you think?

Comment: Can you post the activity code where the fragments are set up?

Comment: What class contains the `onCreateView()` method you showed here. (You should edit the code to include the surrounding class declaration.) How are you creating instances of this class?

Comment: Also, you do not need the `<pre>` tag. Just add 4 spaces before every line of code. Any whitespace after the first four will be used as formatting. As a shortcut, you can paste code in your question, highlight it, and then push Ctrl-K.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice check now. I think the problem is even though the fragment layout is being returned, the java class itself is not being initialized so it never picks up the listeners.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Thanks for the highlighting suggestion. I will keep that in mind.

Comment: Which fragment has the oncreateview method which you added at last of the post?. I think you should move the onclicklistener and other view creation to oncreateView of placeholderfragment of corresponding view in order to work if not

Comment: @AnasAhamed Thank you very much! This worked! How can I mark this comment as the answer?

Comment: I repost it as answer. If you mark this as answer, It will be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which fragment has the oncreateview method which you added at last of the post?. I think you should move the onclicklistener and other view creation to oncreateView of placeholderfragment of corresponding view in order to work if not